# Does PHP empty my array when I equalize the variable to Array()

Tags: php, optimization

My question is,

I have a variable and this holds a list of elements - ie. indexed array.

```
var $myarr;
//added smt. to array..

...

$myarr = Array();
```

Where myarr's elements go? 
Which one is best, above or below? 
Shall I equalize to NULL before to equalize Array()?

```
var $myarr;
//added smt. to array..

...
$myarr = NULL;
$myarr = Array();
```

Comment: Below one is better way.

Comment: I asked this question not because the answer. why?

Comment: @Enes PHP does not have a bare `var` keyword, except for use in classes, where it is deprecated.

Comment: If you mean local variable, don't use `var`.

Comment: Ok, thank you about the warning about var keyword. I'm new in PHP, so I'm using. I won't use it again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$myarr = Array()` will set the value of the variable `$myarr` to an empty array. It does not matter what was there before, whatever it was it is now gone*. There's no difference with first setting `$myarr` to `null`, it's just one more (pointless) step. It does not change anything about the outcome.

<sub>* or at the very least will be garbage collected sometime soon</sub>

Comment: Ok, where my old elements gone when I set it to Array()?

Comment: What do you mean "where they gone"? They're gone. If there's no variable referencing the values anymore, they're gone. `$foo = 1; $foo = 2;` Where did `1` go? It's gone!

Comment: If you're coming from something like C and are thinking in terms of pointers and memory contents: don't. PHP is a garbage collected language.

Comment: As I know PHP uses pointers everywhere. While $myarr pointing an array, when I set it to Array(), does garbage collector run immadiately? Is there **any** difference between to set NULL or smt?

Comment: If you need a primer on PHP's garbage collection: http://php.net/gc And again: no, there's no difference. It's just one more variable assignment.

Comment: btw, you asked "Where did `1` go?" I'm answering it as : There are no `1` before and after you assign it.

Comment: No it does not. 1 is value, array is an object is stored in bulk of memory.

Comment: `1` is a value. An array is a value too. At least in PHP terms. What it does behind the scenes is irrelevant.

Comment: Behind the scenes everything is a zval, integers and arrays alike. See http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch14_06.htm

Answer (score 1):

> Where myarr's elements go?

They are lost. The memory space used will be overwritten by the new array or converted to free space by the garbage collector.

> Which one is best, above or below?

Use the first one. You don't need that extra step. The results are equal.

> Shall I equalize to NULL before to equalize Array()?

You don't need to.

If you want some control over the garbage collector, look at:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.performance-considerations.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php